# How to get to top in every React router dom without the scroll effect?

Tags: reactjs

I found out that there's lot of answers regarding this but all of the solution gives the smooth scrolling effect and I don't need that. It's so annoying to the eyes.

Can someone suggest me some different solution to it?

Comment: you have to do window.scrollTo(0,0); with no scroll behavior options

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.